# SVN, check out folders based on authz

Tags: svn

I've setup a svnserve service on freebsd and trying to figure out the best way to control the auth.

I have root folder A and sub folder A1, A2, A3

```
A--
   |-AdminFolder
   |-Project1
   |-Project2
```

There are 2 role group: g_admin and g_pm. I would like to know how to config authz to fulfill the following scenarios:

1. As a admin I can check-out all folders with read/write permission.
2. As a pm I can only check-out Projectn folders without evening seeing the "AdminFolder"
3. I hope all users are using a same SVN path (SVN://host/A)

I tried the following authz config:

```
[/]
g_admin = rw
* = r

[/A/AdminFolder]
g_admin = rw
* = r

[/A/Project1]
g_admin = rw
g_pm = rw

[/A/Project2]
g_admin = rw
g_pm = rw
```

But then g_pm will see all the content under /...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-read relevant part of [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) (slightly outdated in terms of versions, but usable) and fix some (obvious) parts of config

Because you have "2 role group" in requirements, you *can* add (for more future flexibility) groups section like

```
[groups]
admins = user1, user2
pms= user3, user4
```

and use group's references in rules later

Copy of rules with the same permissions are useless, because authz-rules are inherited from the above path.

As result, you'll get something like (not tested, just written)

```
[groups]
admins = user1, user2
pms = user3, user4

[/]
@admins = rw
* = r

[/A/AdminFolder]
* =

[/A/Project1]
pms = rw

[/A/Project2]
pms = rw
```

Comment: So the problem was not adding `* =`, right? I actually don't see any mentions of this in the book... Was not obvious to me at least, but I guess the `bug-142/secret` kind of suggests that.